# How to generate a unique url for images (imgur.com like) in php?

Tags: php, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

Trying to get something like `https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fB75.jpg`
We know that imgur uses 5 case sensitive string for image. How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string

Comment: Interesting use of image for your example :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just use your auto_increment image id, converted to base58 (a-zA-Z0-9) for example.

[`base_convert`](http://docs.php.net/base_convert) can convert up to base36:

```
$id = base_convert(123456789, 10, 36); // "21i3v9"
```

(See also [PHP - How to base_convert() up to base 62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938029/php-how-to-base-convert-up-to-base-62))

If you want non-predictable image ids, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194506/unique-unpredictable-12-digit-integer-id/7194533#7194533).

---

For MongoDB IDs (as you are using MongoDB):

The ids are 12 bytes numbers, encoded to base16, which makes them 24 bytes.

You can *compress* them to 17 bytes by converting them from base16 to base58:

```
gmp_strval(gmp_init("47cc67093475061e3d95369d", 16), 58)); // "1KXotnQBQbcPmeOo9"
```

Also take a look at the *Sequence Numbers* section [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs). This will allow you to generate smaller unique numbers for your images.

Comment: But... I'm using MongoDB, There is a unique id field like 'shkxjfhsuhgh', so it's not an integer

Comment: then, why not using it ?